# Mock class injection in spring not working as intended

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I recently started writing JUnits that require mocking methods and data. I was able to do this for another class and it worked but not sure why its not working for a current class I'm testing.

Basically what I try to do is.
1.Create a mock class for the class/method that I need to mock the data for.
2.Inject it to the class I'm testing via context.xml
3.When the method is called in the class I'm testing it should be the overridden one

```
public abstract class Service {
    public string methodA(String x, String y, String z) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class SchoolService extends Service{
    public String methodB(String input) {
        String data = methodA("Test", "Test", "Test");
        return data;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class MockService extends SchoolService{
    @Override
    public String methodA(String x, String y, String z) {
        return "OVERRIDE";
    }
}
```

.

```
context.xml

<bean id="SchoolService" class="com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.SchoolService" scope="prototype">
    <property name="SchoolService" ref="MockService"/>
</bean>


<bean id="MockService" class="com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.MockService"/>
```

If this works as what I intend it to do then when methodA is called inside MethodB it should return "OVERRIDE" instead of x.

I wrote this JUnit the same way as I did for the other class but somehow it is not working the same way. I'm suspecting its due it being a super class method, but not sure how I can fix it.

edit: adding my test class

```
public class SchoolServiceTest {
    SchoolService ss;

    @Test
    public string testSchoolService() {
        return ss.methodB("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should look into frameworks like Mockito. Manually extending `SchoolService` and using stuff like a configuration xml aren't necessary with such frameworks for unit tests.

Comment: In your configuration you passed an object of `MockService` as property into `SchoolService` - but it's not such according to your code. (`SchoolService` doesn't have `MockService` property). "If this works as what I intend it to do then when methodA is called inside MethodB it should return "OVERRIDE" instead of x." - if you call `methodA` inside `MockService.methodB` - then you're right, it should return "OVERRIDE".

Comment: @Vusal I added my junit class. So I have SchoolService ss; in there. which if im understanding the configuration correctly. the SchoolService  in the test class should reference the MockService?

Comment: If you want to test the `SchoolService`, don't override its methods. Also you seem to have a typo on your `context.xml`, bean id should be `SchoolService` but is `SchoolServie`.

Comment: @daniu sorry I wrote the wrong method call in the test class. I've updated it. So I want to test the SchoolService class methodB, which calls MethodA(the one I mocked and should return "OVERRIDE" in this case)